# FAA FOQA Program

Tags: safety, commercial-aviation, faa, flight-data-monitoring

The FAA's Flight Operations Quality Assurance (FOQA) program is currently voluntary for some operators. The program allows flight data to be recorded, analyzed, and then submitted to the regulator. Additionally, operators with approved FOQA programs are protected from enforcement under 14 CFR 13.401. What are the pros & cons of joining the regulators FOQA program from the operator stand point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data collected allows your company to analyze how the flight are going.  It records numerous data points which allows the operator to analyze each phase of flight.

- How much runway was required for takeoff?
- Was there a crosswind on takeoff that wasn't corrected for by the pilots?
- Did you drift off the centerline while on approach?
- Were you 50FT AGL crossing the runway threshold?  Were you on the appropriate VREF speed?
- Did you land in the touchdown zone?  When did you apply brakes?

The idea behind collecting and analyzing this data is to see how well operators are adhering to company SOPs, procedures and training.

To answer your question specifically.  Submitting this data to the regulator allows them to understand industry trends and develop training recommendations to reduce the risk in that phase of flight.  I don't know of any cons as the data cannot be used in any investigation.  I feel more data is great to allow better training standards and objective to be created to make pilots better.

I am not associated with C-FOQA or anything like this.
https://vimeo.com/146674763